# How to read JSON file and define Schema in Talend

Tags: talend

Can someone  please tell how to define this Xpath or JSON schema in TALEND 
...I am  trying to read one sample file with tFileInputJSON ...
How to understand the JSON format and write scheme in Talend

```
{
    "id;firstname;lastname;address;date;revenue;states": "1;Andrew;Cleveland;South Roosevelt Drive;20/01/2005;55239;XX"
},
{
    "id;firstname;lastname;address;date;revenue;states": "2;Franklin;Jefferson;Carpinteria Avenue;19/05/2006;78148;NC"
},
{
    "id;firstname;lastname;address;date;revenue;states": "3;Calvin;Cleveland;Corona Del Mar;28/09/2000;77912;CT"
},
{
    "id;firstname;lastname;address;date;revenue;states": "4;Grover;Ford;Cleveland Ave.;27/11/2001;76036;XX"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a metadata in the "repository view > metadata > json (right click then create)".

Find your json on your computer and define the option (you have a visualizer to help you).

Once is ok, you termine the creation and you can use a tinputJSON to read your json with the metadata you just create.